# Small factorials on SPOJ

Tags: java

I am trying to submit my code to the 'Small factorials' problem on SPOJ.
It runs successfully on my IDE but shows run time error (NZEC) on SPOJ. Please suggest a solutions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Factoria
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int t, n;
        int multi = 1;
        Scanner tc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = tc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            Scanner nc = new Scanner(System.in);
            n = nc.nextInt();
            for(int f=1;f<=n;f++){
                multi = multi * f;
            }
            System.out.println(multi);
            multi = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the runtime errors?

Comment: @Blip on some sites like that, it deliberately doesn't give you any information about the output ...

Answer (score 4):

Your runtime error is likely because you try to initiate a new `Scanner` on `System.in` when you already have one open. This seems to fail on Java 8 although seems to run OK on Java 7 - both tested on [ideone](http://ideone.com).  There is no need to initiate a new `Scanner`.

If you simply remove the line

```
Scanner nc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and use `tc.nextInt();` instead of `nc.nextInt();` it should work.

I note you're doing this for an online competition.  You should also note that your factorial will fail (overflow) if the input is > 12 as you're using `int` type.  I don't know whether this will apply in your case.

---

#### Bugfixed code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Factoria
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int t, n;
        int multi = 1;
        Scanner tc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = tc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            n = tc.nextInt();
            for(int f=1;f<=n;f++){
                multi = multi * f;
            }
            System.out.println(multi);
            multi = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Input

```
5
4
3
5
2
1
```

#### Output

```
24
6
120
2
1
```